# How to disable welcome message after SSH login?

Tags: server, ssh, login, motd

I have changed `/etc/issue.net`, so I have set a "personal" message after typing a username in an SSH terminal. Now I am trying to change the welcome text after successful login.

I have found a lot of posts about the `/etc/motd` file, but the part "Welcome to Ubuntu blabla versionnumber and so on" +  "* Documentation URL " is not there?

I just do not want to show OS info in my SSH terminal, I already know what I have installed. :)
I only want to see my last login. And also not errors; errors belong in a logfile.

Which file do I have to edit?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The welcome messages are generated by the files residing in `/etc/update-motd.d/`.

From `man update-motd`:

> Executable scripts in /etc/update-motd.d/* are executed by pam_motd(8)
>   as the root user at each login, and this information
>          is  concatenated  in  /var/run/motd.

So if you don't want the outputs of those scripts upon login via `ssh` just remove the execute flag on them:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

Now if you want to show something you want upon login, you have two options:

- Make a script, put it in `/etc/update-motd.d/`, make it executable, also make sure it outputs on STDOUT.
- `ssh` has a `Banner` option. You can put the text in a file and set it in the `Banner` option so that the content of the file is shown upon login via `ssh`. Note that this is applicable to only `ssh`.

  ```
  Banner /etc/foobar
  ```

  From `man 5 sshd_config`:

  ```
   Banner  The contents of the specified file are sent to the remote user
           before authentication is allowed.  If the argument is “none” then
           no banner is displayed.  This option is only available for
           protocol version 2.  By default, no banner is displayed.
  ```

Comment: My favorite answers all start with "From man xyz" ;)

Comment: Thank you! Now i know the relationship between those files. I did not chmod them, just added # before some lines i do not want to show.

Comment: @Terradon Yeah, that would do too..i just generalized the solution because many people won't like to look into the file much..

Comment: Great clean solution because `chmoding` the files means I don't have to edit them. Nice!

Comment: ...why do they put so much crap in the motd and waste people's time disabling it  :s  Nice solution with the chmod -x !

Comment: changing x permission with chmod doesn't work :(

Comment: I disabled all those messages in `/etc/update-motd/` but I still get a `No mail` and `Last login:` message.

Comment: Standard seems to be that sort <= 50 is garbage, and sort > 50 is usefull status checks.

Comment: If disabling x permission with chmod doesn't work, it means it is necessary to edit another files in `/etc/update-motd/` direcotry

Comment: It does not work for everyone.

Answer (score 66):

Another way that does not require administrative rights is to place an empty file called

```
.hushlogin
```

into your $HOME directory (using for example `touch ~/.hushlogin`).

The downside to this solution is that you might miss a message saying something like

```
Last login: Wed Aug 22 16:00:10 2007 from l33t.hax0r.some.ips
```

that indicates your account has been compromised.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924150633/https://debian-administration.org/article/546/Giving_yourself_a_quieter_SSH_login).

Comment: Elegant, simple, doesn't mess with other users, no `sudo`. Thanks.

Comment: this is not "another way" but the best way !

Comment: this should be the most upvoted answer

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Comment: @PhilippeRemy The user explicitly said that he wants to see the last login information. This answer hides the last login information.

Answer (score 6):

You can also nuke `pam_motd` altogether:

```
sed -i '/^[^#]*\<pam_motd.so\>/s/^/#/' /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

PAM calls `pam_motd` depending on the settings in `/etc/pam.d`, and typically the entries are:

```
$ grep pam_motd /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]
```

Just commenting out the `pam_motd` lines from these files will disable it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but with "Nuke them all" i dont know what i am doing. (I am new to linux/ubuntu).

Comment: @Terradon you're telling PAM not to call `pam_motd.so`, that's all.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a closer look at what PAM.does exactly.

Answer (score 6):

There might also be file under `/etc/motd` containing a welcome message which can easily be removed (the content).

Comment: Thanks this was the case on Debian 10, and a nice quick easy fix!