# How do I disable the Message of the Day (MOTD) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ssh, motd, banner

I tried disabling the motd.dynamic in /var/run renaming the file, but did not work because the system recreates the file.

Does anyone know disable it?

Comment: The motd file does not exist in /etc. How I do?

Answer (score 50):

Most answers need root access.

Any user can get a clean login(include disabling the MOTD), simply run:

```
touch $HOME/.hushlogin
```

Answer (score 22):

The script files in `/etc/update-motd.d` generate the file  `/var/run/motd.dynamic` which you've identified as containing your MOTD.

A simplistic way to stop generating this file would be to make all of the scripts non-executable with:

```
chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

Note: Information taken from [this answer by heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/a/676381/320386).

Comment: If it solved your problem would you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the little grey tick/check mark :)

Comment: I love how this is the first thing I have to do with any new Ubuntu install - delete stuff.

Comment: @ecnepsnai "user-friendly" distributions are almost always bloated—that's what you get when trying to satisfy most of the users.

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to comment out these lines in `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
#session    optional    pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
#session    optional    pam_motd.so noupdate
```

Answer (score 14):

If anyone landed here because they specifically wanted to disable the ["news"](https://motd.ubuntu.com) (ie. ads/promotional blurbs for things like macOS Kubernetes tooling) portion of the dynamic MOTD, but don't mind the rest being there (eg. the pending updates notification), that's easy too.

At the time I wrote this, this was the ad being displayed:

```
 * "If you've been waiting for the perfect Kubernetes dev solution for
   macOS, the wait is over. Learn how to install Microk8s on macOS."

   https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-microk8s-on-macos/
```

Just open up `/etc/default/motd-news` and set `ENABLED=0`.

Answer (score 7):

As per Alcuin Arundel's answer, also edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and comment out the pam_motd lines to remove the messages when entering through ssh.

Answer (score 1):

There is configuration option in `sshd_config`, called `PrintMotd`. Setting it to `no` does the job.

Comment: The design is so sad that the scripts are run even if SSH is set to PrintMotd no. I think pam is really the best way out, it seems the noupdate setting there *should* tame this, but it doesn't.

Comment: As @FlorianHeigl suggests, this doesn't work.

Comment: The question is about disabling motd in the ssh, which the answer really does. But from your comment nor form the florian is not clear what does not work. If you have a different problem or question, there is a button up there.

Comment: @Jakuje It means (also in my case, although I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 which didn't exist in 2018) that you get the exact same motd even with PrintMotd set to no. Which in my case is the default anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround/hack

```
 ssh -t IP_ADDRESS bash
```

`-t` to force tty allocation

send the `bash` command, as sending a command doesn't output any of the bannery business.

have fun

Comment: I love it when an answer provides me food-for-thought on some tangential issue.  Not directly on this, but usable elsewhere.  Thanx.